# bind_rustls method from rustls when using with actix-web is throwing error on mismatched type of ServerConfig

Tags: ssl, rust, https, actix-web

I am trying to make my `actix-web` server accept https requests and written following code for the same.

```
use std::{fs::File, io::BufReader};

use actix_files::Files;
use actix_web::{
    http::header::ContentType, middleware, web, App, HttpRequest, HttpResponse, HttpServer,
};
use log::debug;
use rustls::{Certificate, PrivateKey, ServerConfig};
use rustls_pemfile::{certs, pkcs8_private_keys};

/// simple handle
async fn index(req: HttpRequest) -> HttpResponse {
    debug!("{req:?}");

    HttpResponse::Ok().content_type(ContentType::html()).body(
        "<!DOCTYPE html><html><body>\
            <p>Welcome to your TLS-secured homepage!</p>\
        </body></html>",
    )
}

#[actix_web::main]
async fn main() -> std::io::Result<()> {
    env_logger::init_from_env(env_logger::Env::default().default_filter_or("info"));

    let config = load_rustls_config();

    log::info!("starting HTTPS server at https://localhost:8443");

    HttpServer::new(|| {
        App::new()
            // enable logger
            .wrap(middleware::Logger::default())
            // register simple handler, handle all methods
            .service(web::resource("/index.html").to(index))
            .service(web::redirect("/", "/index.html"))
            .service(Files::new("/static", "static"))
    })
    .bind_rustls("127.0.0.1:8443", config)?
    .run()
    .await
}

fn load_rustls_config() -> rustls::ServerConfig {
    // init server config builder with safe defaults
    let config = ServerConfig::builder()
        .with_safe_defaults()
        .with_no_client_auth();

    // load TLS key/cert files
    let cert_file = &mut BufReader::new(File::open("cert.pem").unwrap());
    let key_file = &mut BufReader::new(File::open("key.pem").unwrap());

    // convert files to key/cert objects
    let cert_chain = certs(cert_file)
        .unwrap()
        .into_iter()
        .map(Certificate)
        .collect();
    let mut keys: Vec<PrivateKey> = pkcs8_private_keys(key_file)
        .unwrap()
        .into_iter()
        .map(PrivateKey)
        .collect();

    // exit if no keys could be parsed
    if keys.is_empty() {
        eprintln!("Could not locate PKCS 8 private keys.");
        std::process::exit(1);
    }

    config.with_single_cert(cert_chain, keys.remove(0)).unwrap()
}
```

which I got from official example of `rustls` implementation in `actix-web` from [here](https://github.com/actix/examples/blob/master/https-tls/rustls/src/main.rs). But I am getting a following compile error on call of `bind_rustls` method:

```
struct `ServerConfig` and struct `rustls::server::server_conn::ServerConfig` have similar names, but are actually distinct types perhaps two different versions of crate `rustls` are being used?
```

I am not sure what should I change. I also tried to change the import from `rustls::ServerConfig` to `rustls::server::ServerConfig` but it doesn't work. `rustls::server::server_conn::ServerConfig` is a private struct so I am not able to import it.

Comment: Did you check the with for example `cargo tree` for different versions of `rustls` like the error message suggests might be the problem? (hint actix depends on `rustls@0.20.8` and the latest is `rustls@0.21.0` which you probably have installed)

Comment: Same underlying problem, just different crates: [How do I fix my compatability errors when using plotters::CairoBackend with GTK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75229974/how-do-i-fix-my-compatability-errors-when-using-plotterscairobackend-with-gtk)

Comment: Fair point. It worked on changing the version of rustls. Thanks.